# Python name 'OAuth2Session' is not defined on windows10

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, windows-10

I run this code

> from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
>
> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>
> import oauth2
>
> import oauth
>
> tokens_url = "https://x123.com/oauth/token"
>
> client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
>
> oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
>
> token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=tokens_url, client_id=client_id,
>
> client_secret=client_secret)

and I get NameError: name 'OAuth2Session' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
```

You may need to [install requests_oauthlib using pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-oauthlib) if it hasn't already been installed on your system.

Comment: I tried that also, I get ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib

Comment: You'll have to install that using pip

Comment: I don't have linux. Is there a way to install it on windows with pip?

Comment: Depending on your version of python, pip should be included by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I did it and I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "c:\python27\pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
ImportError: No module named commands.install

Comment: @ David I only managed to install pip after installing python ver 3.6. and download the requests_oauthlib. It was impossible to install pip under python 2.7 on Windows 10. After that it worked. So if you like please edit and add to your answer that Windows users have to install pip and I will mark it as correct. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Cheetara Glad you got it working. I've added the additional instructions to my answer.